# SingleEmailMessage SetWhatId with Quote Id

Tags: email, quote, platform-bug, whatid

I am currently recreating much of the OOB `Quote` functionality in Apex and I am *almost* complete. Now there is just one other hurdle, the **Email Quote** functionality.

Now, it doesn't seem like an issue.... at first.

I am able to create a `QuoteDocument`, set it up as an attachment, setup my email message with a template, and even create a task for the email being sent. **However**, as soon as I set the `WhatId` using the `setWhatId` method, I get the following error:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only accounts, assets, campaigns, cases, contracts, opportunities, orders, products, solutions and custom objects are allowed as whatId.: []

Now, the error message states that the OOB `Quote` object that I am using cannot be linked to a `Task` using the `WhatId`. Now, I would have gladly stopped there, but the problem is, there is a lot of functionality that contradicts this error.

Here are some red flags that make me believe there should be some way to set the `WhatId` with a `Quote` Id.

### **Red Flags**

**Red Flag #1:** *Email Quote button not only creates an e-mail but a `Task`, which is shown on the Activity History related list on the Quote detail page*.

---

The standard **Email Quote** button *does* create a `Task` when the e-mail is sent. The only way it would show up on the `Quote`'s detail page, in the Activity History related list no less, is if that `Task` was linked via the `WhatId`. Furthermore, you can create a new `Task` for the `Quote` via the Open Activities related list.
[image: Activity Related List with Task]

**Red Flag #2:** *`Task` detail page shows Related To field going to a `Quote`*

---

When I clicked on the `Task` created by the **Email Quote** button, I looked at the **Related To** field (which is the `WhatId`), it links to the `Quote` I created.
[image: Task Detail Part One]
Now, I thought that maybe it was a mistake, so I chose to edit the `Task`. But in doing so, it just verified that it was linking to the `Quote`.
[image: Task Detail Part 2]

**Red Flag #3 (the major one):** *When I query the `Task` and inspect the `WhatId`, it **IS** the Quote Id!*

---

So to completely verify that the `Task`'s `WhatId` was being set with a Quote Id, I decided to query the `Task` using Execute Anonymous. So I entered the following code:

```
Task taskLinkingToQuote = [SELECT WhatId FROM Task 
    WHERE Id = '00Tj0000009PsWZ' LIMIT 1];
System.Debug(LoggingLevel.Info, taskLinkingToQuote);
```

But, lo and behold, the `WhatId` was set the `Quote`.

[image: Debug Log Linking To Quote]

So, somehow, it *seems* that the **Email Quote** button can not only create a `Task` but, it can link the `Quote` to it via the `WhatId`.

---

So now all I can say about the `WhatId` issue is **W.T.F.!?** (Sorry, couldn't resist.) This functionality should work in Apex. Hell, there is even code out right now that depends on it, [like this one](http://backup-ui-parx.googlecode.com/svn/src/classes/QuotePdfUtility.cls).

Apparently, it worked before. There has even been an issue raised about it [here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4C0AAI).

So has anyone run into and resolved this issue? Is there anyway around this issue? I haven't tried simply creating a new `Task` yet, but I wouldn't want to go through the effort and run into the same error.

I would simply like to have the `Task` appear on the correct detail page - the `Quote`'s. I currently have to suffice with the `Opportunity`, but I'd like to get the functionality to operate as if it is OOB.

Comment: You are using OOB `Quote` or custom  `Quote__c`? In the former case, the error message states that `Quote` is not one of the allowed use cases

Comment: I am currently using the OOB Quote. I understand that the error states that this use case isn't allowed. However, this use case is done OOB - contradicting what the error message is saying. I changed my question to highlight the issue.

Comment: +1 for the WhatId to WTF association; while I don't know the specific answer to this, I'm sure you can independently insert a Task via DML after you send the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got around to fixing the issue.

Just as [@crop1645](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2602/crop1645) said, if I simply `INSERT` the `Task` via a DML statement, I will be able to create a `Task` with a `Quote`'s Id as the `WhatId`.

So before, as a recap, I tried something like this:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage newEmail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
newEmail.setToAddresses(new List<String> { emailAddress });
newEmail.setTargetObjectId(quoteBeingUsed.ContactId);
newEmail.setWhatId(quotesId);
newEmail.setTemplateId(TemplateId);
newEmail.setFileAttachments(new List<Messaging.EmailFileAttachment> { newAttachment });
Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> { newEmail });
```

This resulted in throwing the following exception:

> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_ID_FIELD, Only accounts, assets, campaigns, cases, contracts, opportunities, orders, products, solutions and custom objects are allowed as whatId.: []

Now how I solved it was simple. However, I wanted to make sure I got the `Task` information **exactly** like it was done by the **Email Quote** button. I changed the `WhatId` for the `SingleEmailMessage` to the related `OpportunityId` and after the `sendEmail` method I followed it with:

```
Task newQuoteEmailTask = new Task(Subject = 'Email: ' + newEmail.getSubject(), 
     OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId(), WhatId = quotesId, WhoId = quoteBeingUsed.ContactId,
     Status = 'Completed', ActivityDate = Date.today(), Priority = 'Normal', 
     Description = GenerateTaskComment(newEmail));
INSERT newQuoteEmailTask;
```

The `Description`'s method is the following:

```
private static String GenerateTaskComment(Messaging.SingleEmailMessage newEmail)
{
    List<String> listOfFileNames = new List<String>();

    for(Messaging.EmailFileAttachment singleAttachment : newEmail.getFileAttachments())
        listOfFileNames.add(singleAttachment.getFileName());

    String endOfDescription = '_____________________________________________________________________'
    + '\nPowered by salesforce.com\nhttp://www.salesforce.com/';

    return 'Additional To: '+ String.join(newEmail.getToAddresses() != null ? newEmail.getToAddresses() : new List<String>(), ',')
        + '\nCC: ' + String.join(newEmail.getCcAddresses() != null ? newEmail.getCcAddresses() : new List<String>(), ',') 
        + '\nBCC: ' + String.join(newEmail.getBccAddresses() != null ? newEmail.getBccAddresses() : new List<String>(), ',') 
        + '\nAttachment'+ (listOfFileNames.size() > 1 ? 's' : '') + ': ' + String.join(listOfFileNames, ',')
        + '\n\nSubject: ' + newEmail.getSubject()
        + '\nBody:\n' + newEmail.getPlainTextBody()
        + '\n\n' + endOfDescription;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Quote can be associated as WhatId now. I just tested this. See this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l4C0AAI